# Vagrant file structure and web root

Tags: vagrant

I've read the docs and a few things still confuse me, mostly related to sync folders and database data.

I want to use the following folder structure on my host machine

`ROOT

|- workFolder

||- project1

|||- project1DatabaseAndFiles

|||- project1WebRoot

||- project2

|||- project2DatabaseAndFiles

|||- project2WebRoot

||- project3

|||- project3DatabaseAndFiles

|||- project3WebRoot`

And then create VM's where each VM host webroot points to the appropriate projectX/projectXWebRoot folder.
From what I've read, I can only specify one remote Sync DIR. (http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/). But if I create a new VM I want to specify the project name too, thereby selecting the correct host folder.

Is what I'm describing possible using Vagrant?
If I wanted another developer to use this environment, I'd like for them to have instant access to the database structure/setup etc without having to import any SQL files. Is this possible?

I'm hoping I'm just not understanding Vagrants purpose, but this seems like a good use of shared VM's to me. Any pointers or articles that might help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I've read, I can only specify one remote Sync DIR.

No that is not true. You can always add more shared folders. From the 
[manual](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/share_folder.html):

> This directive is used to configure shared folders on the virtual machine and may be used multiple times in a Vagrantfile.

This means you can define additional shared folders using:

```
  config.vm.share_folder "name", "/path/on/vm", "path/on/host"
```

> If I wanted another developer to use this environment, I'd like for them to have instant access to the database structure/setup etc without having to import any SQL files. Is this possible?

Yes, you can alter the data storage path of, say, MySQL to store it in on a share on the host so that
the data is not lost when the VM is destroyed.

However, this is not as simple as it sounds. If you're using the MySQL cookbook (again, assuming you're using MySQL), you have to modify it so that the shared folder is mounted with the uid and gid of the mysql user or otherwise the user can't write to it. You can mount a share manually like this:

```
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u mysql` -o gid=`id -g mysql` sharename /new/data/dir
```

Also, if you're using Ubuntu or Debian Wheezy, Apparmor needs to be configured differently for MySQL,
as it does not allow writes to the newly configured data directory. This can be done by writing

```
/new/data/dir r,
/new/data/dir/** rwk,
```

to `/etc/apparmor/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld`. [This version](https://github.com/githubnemo/mysql) of the mysql cookbook supports this behaviour already, so you can look up how it does that.

Comment: Cheers for the quick reply! I'm off to read this in great detail!!

Comment: Ah, I was trying to instantiate each instance from one folder. I didn't realise that each project can have its own vagrantFile and specific settings. When I navigate to a project, I can then do vargrant up and it starts the specific instance required.

I'm still a way off from understanding everything, but this fact wasted a day.. d'oh.. :)